# Set Jenkins Global Variables - init.groovy.d

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am looking to set some configurations in Jenkins as part of a Docker build and using the init.groovy.d scripts to do so.

I am able to run the below code successfully when a Global Property already exists, but when there are no Global Properties in place the script is successful but the property is not added.

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
println "--> setting Global properties (Environment variables)..."
def globalProps = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.globalNodeProperties
def props = globalProps.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
for (prop in props) {
prop.envVars.put("PATH", "/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin")
}
instance.save()
println "--> setting Global properties (Environment variables)... done!"
```

How can I run this command in a Jenkins instance with no global properties already set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the for loop essentially looping over an empty array. Fixed by changing the code. No issue with Jenkins, just my implementation!

```
 if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
}

envVars.put("PATH", "/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin")
```